# How can I prevent some profiles to comment social posts?

Tags: socialpost

I'm new on SFDC Social Media. I need to prevent some users to comment social posts. They can see the social posts but not respond. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For this you are going to have to use an Apex Trigger. It will be something like the following:

```
trigger FeedCommentBefore on FeedComment(Before Insert) {

Id UserProfile = UserInfo.getProfileId();

profile MyProfile = [SELECT id FROM profile WHERE name = 'MyProfile'];

for(FeedComment fc : trigger.new)
    if((fc.CommentType== 'ContentComment' || fc.CommentType== 'TextComment' ) && UserProfile == MyProfile.Id)
        fc.addError('You don't have the correct permissions to Comment on Chatter Posts.');
}
```

You will just need to change all of the instances of MyProfile to the profile you would like to restrict from commenting.

Comment: Hi cmmoutes13! I've found other way to restric users to respond social posts. I've just created a new page layout where I removed the "social" button from the layout and assigned to the profiles that cannot respond social posts. Thanks anyway!